# Pure Javascript end()

Tags: javascript

How to recreate a jQuery `end()`

`$('#id')` `.find('.class')` `.css('font',f)` `.end()` `.find('.seven')` `.css(b,'red')`

## What I Have

`$('#id')` = `.getElementById()`
`.find('.class')` = `.querySelectorAll()`
`.css('font',f)` = `for loop` `change css`

> .end() --- Here lies my problem… I don't know how to return back to the first element in the chain

`.find('.seven')` = `.querySelectorAll()`
`.css(b,'red')` = `for loop` `change css`

Does Javascript have an `.end()` that's baked into it that I don't know about?

Comment: No, there's not a javascript `end()` function.  It's just a way to tell jQuery "I'm done with the selector results returned by `find`, go back to considering that I'm working on the previous object.  If you store a reference to whatever your `getElementById` returned, then `end` would set `this = myElem` (conceptually).  It's probably a bit more advanced under the hood, but it's not something that's directly analogous to some javascript behavior (though maybe you could get there with scope / function calls / closures?)

Comment: There is no end function baked into the DOM api. Have you tried looking through jQuery source to see how they solve the problem?

Comment: I'm not good at reading other peoples code… wish I could but… that's a little too advanced for me

Comment: The javascript way would be to use a drat simple *variable*. No chaining.

Comment: So if I put a var firstChainItem = document.getElementById('id')

Comment: create a .find() that updates previous item

Comment: No, you don't update the variable. Just just write `const item = document.getElementById('id'); for (const el of item.querySelectorAll('.class')) /* update css */; for (const el of item.querySelectorAll('.seven')) /* update css */;` where you use `item` multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

When You check jQuery source code, You will see that they are pushing each element on stack. Then each use of `end()` function pop previous object from the stack. You would have to do simple version of this aproach.